# How to rollback in saga pattern when a service fails

Tags: java, rabbitmq, spring-cloud, producer-consumer, saga

I am starting with Saga pattern using Spring cloud and rabbit mq. Following is the problem statement:
I call /service1 (producer) which publishes a message in rabbit mq and that message is consumed by the consumer service.

Now occurs tow cases:

**Case 1**: Consumer service does its part successfully.

**Case 2**: Consumer service fails to do its part, thus /service1 has to rollback its changes.

How does /service1 know if consumer is successful or not, so that it can send a success/failure response. Following is the project structure:

Producer:

```
    @RestController
    public class ProducerController {
        
        private MessageChannel greet;
        
        public ProducerController(HelloBinding binding) {
            greet = binding.greeting();
        }
        
        @GetMapping("/greet/{name}")
        public void publish(@PathVariable String name) {
            String greeting = "Hello, "+name+"!";
            Message<String> msg = MessageBuilder.withPayload(greeting)
                                                .build();
            this.greet.send(msg);
            System.out.println("Message sent to the queue");
            AMQP.Basic.Ack;
            
}
```

Consumer:

```
@EnableBinding(HelloBinding.class)
public class HelloListener {
    
    @StreamListener(target=HelloBinding.GREETING)
    public void processHelloChannelGreeting(String msg) {
        System.out.println("Message received:- "+msg);
    }

}
```

Now how do I tell the producer whether consumer's action is a success or a failure so that producer service sends appropriate response?

Answer (score 2):

The producer can not know what happens after a message has been successfully published to a topic. If you want feedback from the consumer then you need to create a new "response" topic on which the consumer communicates success or failure of processing that message.

You can map the messages by keys.